# Circular dependancy in Spring due to Audit Columns

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing a small application where I want to have audit columns in tables. I want to store below fields

1. Created_by
2. Created_On
3. Modified_by
4. Modified_on

In my hibernate entities, this is making a circular dependency. Due to this, my service classes in service layer also has circular dependency. Spring does not seem to like this, and is throwing `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`.

I am using `XML` based **setter injection**, and **not autowiring**. All the solutions I am getting online suggest that `XML` based injection should be used rather than **autowiring**.

How should I resolve this issue?

Below is the `XML` configuration

```
<bean id="memberService" class="xxx.MemberServiceImpl">
    <property name="manager" ref="memberManager"/>
    <property name="mTypeService" ref="membershipTypeService"/>
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"/>
    <property name="pFeeRecordService" ref="pFeeRecordService"/> 
</bean>
<bean id="pFeeRecordService" class="xxx.PendingFeeRecordServiceImpl">
    <property name="manager" ref="pFeeRecordManager"/>
    <property name="memberService" ref="memberService"/>
</bean>
```

Note the property named `pFeeRecordService` injected in `memberService`, which itself is using `memberService`.

Comment: If possible, can you post the code as unable to make on what is causing the issue

Comment: as of now, I have resolved this problem by adding `default-lazy-init="true" ` in my servlet.xml file. But I would like to get better solution.

Comment: Well as you know you have a circular dependency. memberService depends on pFeeRecordService and vice versa. The standard refactor on this is to create a 3rd service, that injects the other two, pulling up methods into that 3rd process as needed.

By the way I strongly recommend that you 

a) don't use XML in Spring, it's incredibly cumbersome compared to programmatic and

b) use constructor injection.